# how to loop over string variable in R

Tags: r

How to use the names in the string vector in models? for example why cant I do this

```
loop_variables = c("Age", "BMI", "Height")

for (i in 1:length(loop_variables){
    basic_logistic_model = glm(outcome~loop_variable[i], data=DB, family="binomial"
    summary(basic_logistic_model)
}
```

I see alot of R users doing vectors with names of study variables then looping it
what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the formula that needs to be update.  We may use `paste` or `reformulate`.  In addition, it is better to have an object to store the output of summary especially a `list` would suit.

```
summary_lst <- vector('list', length(loop_variables))
names(summary_lst) <- loop_variables
for (i in 1:length(loop_variables){
    # convert the column to factor column
    DB[[loop_variables[i]]] <- factor(DB[[loop_variables[i]]])
    # create the formula
    fmla <- reformulate(loop_variable[i], response = 'outcome')
    basic_logistic_model = glm(fmla, data=DB, family="binomial")
    # assign the summary output to the list element
    summary_lst[[i]] <- summary(basic_logistic_model)
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but how can I apply this if I want to do lets say: 
I want to convert the loop variables into factors how can I use DB$loop_variable[i] in this case?

Answer (score 0):

In my view, data transformation part (e.g. converting variables into factors) and modelling part (e.g. using `glm()`) ought to be separated and not to be mixed in the loop for the code readability and efficiency.

Here, I will show how to execute looping iterations using `purrr::map()`, while  the data to be analysed is transformed using `dplyr::mutate()` beforehand.

### Package loading

```r
library(purrr) # for `map`, `set_names`
library(dplyr) # for `mutate`
```

### Data transformation

#### Add new variables that was converted into factors using dummy coding

```r
fct_ToothGrowth <- ToothGrowth |>
  mutate(
    fct_dose = dose |>
      as.factor()
    fct_len = len |>
      ## The numeric variable `len` is converted
      ## into a three-level factor 
      cut(3) |>
      as.factor()
  )

contrasts(fct_ToothGrowth$fct_dose)
contrasts(fct_ToothGrowth$fct_len)
```

#### Add new variables that was converted into factors using non-dummy coding

[Sum contrast](https://stats.oarc.ucla.edu/r/library/r-library-contrast-coding-systems-for-categorical-variables/#DEVIATIONhttps://stats.oarc.ucla.edu/r/library/r-library-contrast-coding-systems-for-categorical-variables/#DEVIATION) and [forward difference coding](https://stats.oarc.ucla.edu/r/library/r-library-contrast-coding-systems-for-categorical-variables/#forward) are used here as examples.

```
fct_ToothGrowth <- ToothGrowth |>
  mutate(
    fct_dose = `contrasts<-`(
      factor(
        dose,
        levels = c("0.5", "1", "2")
      ), ,
      ## sum contrast coding (as known as deviation coding)
      contr.sum(3)
    ),
    fct_len = `contrasts<-`(
      factor(
        cut(len, 3)
      ), ,
      ## Forward difference coding
      MASS::contr.sdif(3)
    )
  )

contrasts(fct_ToothGrowth$fct_dose)
contrasts(fct_ToothGrowth$fct_len)
```

### Looping `glm()`

```
explanatory_variables <- c("fct_len", "fct_dose", "len", "dose")

summaries <- map(
  .x = explanatory_variables,
  ## "fct_len", "fct_dose", "len", and "dose" are replaced
  ## by the arguments specified in `.x`. 
  ~ paste0("supp ~ ", .x) |>
  ## `supp ~ fct_len`, ..., `supp ~ dose` are inputted
  ## into the first argument of `glm()`, namely `formula` argument 
    glm(family = binomial, data = fct_ToothGrowth)
) |>
  ## set names to the returned sublists
  set_names(nm = explanatory_variables)

summaries$fct_len
summaries$fct_dose
summaries$len
summaries$dose
```