# No applicable method for 'lme' applied to an object of class "character"

Tags: r, regression, mixed-models, nlme

I get the following error:

```
Error in UseMethod("lme") : 
  no applicable method for 'lme' applied to an object of class "character"
```

when running my code:

```
outcome = "Score"
exposures_fixed = c("Age", "Sex","BMI")
coefficients = c()
for (k in 1:length(exposures_fixed) { 
  fix_exp = exposures_fixed [k]
  Formula = paste0(outcome,"~", fix_exp)
  mixed_model= lme(fixed = Formula, random = ~1|ID, data = DB,
                   na.action = na.omit, method = "ML")
  coef = mixed_model$coefficients$fixed[2]
  coefficients = rbind(coefficients, coef)
}
```

I guess the problem is that `Formula` is a string, not a real formula. How can I fix this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to loop over string variable in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73224548/how-to-loop-over-string-variable-in-r)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the moment you have a string

```
Formula = paste0(outcome, "~", fix_exp)
```

To coerce it to a formula, you can use

```
formula(Formula)
```

Alternatively, you can directly construct a formula using

```
reformulate(fix_exp, outcome)
```

---

**Lesson Learned:** `lm` and `glm` can handle a formula in string format, but `lme` can't.